# Pick A Brick delivery times

Tags: pick-a-brick

I am about to order some bricks using the online [Pick A Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) service. Unfortunately, its delivery time information is confusing. In the right column of the checkout page, it says:

> Your item will be delivered in up to 5 business days.

However, in the left column, it says:

> Please allow up to 15 business days (Monday through Friday excluding
>   holidays) for delivery time.

So, which one is correct? What's your experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the UK, about two weeks.  I have used the service maybe seven times and it hasn't been less than a week.

Answer (score 5):

Pick-A-Brick orders are shipped from Denmark so they take longer, and they also need more processing time. In my experience they take 2 weeks to arrive. I'm in the USA. Hope this helps.

Comment: i found it to be more like 3 weeks around the holidays

Comment: Yes, around the holidays pretty much all orders get delayed.

Answer (score 1):

The LEGO catalog says that orders in stock will deliver within 3-8 business days and "LEGO® Pick a Brick, please allow an additional 10 business days for processing time." So if you do the math, its really somewhere between 13-18 business days excluding holidays